# Obtaining value by dereferencing pointers

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int age = 40;
    float gpa = 3.25f;
    char grade ='A';
    double fun = 2.000043f;
    char companyName[20] = "O'Brien Enterprises";

    int *pAge = &age;
    int *pGpa = &gpa;
    int *pGrade = &grade;
    int *pFun = &fun;
    int *pCompanyName = &companyName;

    printf("Value of variables through pointers:\n");
    printf("age = %i\n", *pAge);
    printf("gpa = %f\n",*pGpa);
    printf("grade = %c\n", *pGrade);
    printf("fun = %d\n", *pFun);
    printf("companyName = %s\n", *pCompanyName);


    return 0;
}
```

When i run this code Xcode replies with a ton of warnings and errors. When declaring and intializing the pointers for all variables except for `age` it says `incompatible pointer types`. And when attempting to print them out, it  says for all but `age`,`format specifies a different type`. Why is this? And when the code is run as is I get the following results:

```
Value of variables through pointers:
age = 40
gpa = 0.000000
grade = A
fun = -2147483648
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 5):

You've declared all of them as pointers to integers whereas they should be a pointer to an `int`, a `float`, a `char`, and so on!

```
int *pAge = &age;
float *pGpa = &gpa;
char *pGrade = &grade;
double *pFun = &fun;
char **pCompanyName = &companyName;
```

Comment: Oh! I was under the interpretation that they were all supposed to be integers because they all pointed to a memory address?

Comment: It is the nature of pointers that they point to a memory address, but what's at that memory address does not need to be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int age = 40;
    float gpa = 3.25f;
    char grade ='A';
    double fun = 2.000043f;
    char companyName[20] = "O'Brien Enterprises";

    int *pAge = &age;
    float *pGpa = &gpa;
    char *pGrade = &grade;
    double *pFun = &fun;
    char *pCompanyName = companyName;

    printf("Value of variables through pointers:\n");
    printf("age = %i\n", *pAge);
    printf("gpa = %f\n",*pGpa);
    printf("grade = %c\n", *pGrade);
    printf("fun = %f\n", *pFun);
    printf("companyName = %s\n", pCompanyName );


    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Value of variables through pointers:
age = 40
gpa = 3.250000
grade = A
fun = 2.000043
companyName = O'Brien Enterprises
```

You have to use corect pointer types and format specifiers in printf function.

Or if you want to have a pointer to a character array then you can write

```
char ( *pCompanyName )[20] = &companyName;
```

and correspondingly

```
printf("companyName = %s\n", *pCompanyName );
```

Comment: The OP wants each variable in the second group to be a pointer to whatever the variable in the first group is equal to. So that last one should be `char **`, not `char *`.

Comment: Xcode replies to `char **pCompanyName = &companyName;` with a warning of "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'char **' with an expression of type 'char(*)(20)'" and when i run the code an error appears next to `printf("companyName = %s\n", *pCompanyName );` saying "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPLFT)". I am unsure what either of these things mean.

Comment: @Justin O'Brien Oh, I am sorry. See my updated post. There shall be char ( *pCompanyName )[20] = &companyName;